# going back 1 page using php

Tags: php, back, browser-history

In my footer I have

```
header("Location: galleries.php");
```

Is it possible to use php code (or something) to just go 1 page back instead of using a specific page like `galleries.php`?

Using something like `history.go(-1)` won't work since the `header("Location: galleries.php");` is in PHP.

Comment: Try using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. I guess you can accomplish some sort of back function with it.

Comment: try This header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)"); or   
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: @Mehul header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)"); dont work

Comment: @Mehul @Y U NO WORK the code: header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); just refresh the page and does not go back to the previus page. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I hope this is usefull echo " <script language='JavaScript'>history.go(-1);</script>";

Comment: @Mehul thanks, but it needs to be in the header('Location:____"); so I cant use a script since ints in the php and need the "Location" in front of it. I think it has to be a php code that can send the use 1 page back or a given link

Answer (score 2):

Try this for go to previous page,

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: Ha! Knew it. Was just too scared that it would be wrong. :D

Comment: @YUNOWORK Yes. It's may or may not be work, because its depends on the  `userAgent`. But these guy, not interested to go with `JS`

Comment: @Ranjith the code: header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); just refresh the page and does not go back to the previus page. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @GernerChristensen Ya. That time its doesn't work. The way you can achieve this storing the previous page `URI` into one `Session` variable. For example, `$_SESSION['previous_page'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`. Before assigning that, you need to check both `$_SESSION['previous_page']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])` are not equally.

Comment: @Ranjith hmmm I have tried to add: header("Location: ".$_SESSION['previous_page'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); but the page does just still reload. Here is what should happens: I got from page A to page B. On page B I fill out a form and click update. I should then go back to page A. The reason why I cant just give a URL in the location is because there are many different pages that link to the form. So I have page A, C, D, E that all links to page B and when you click update on page B you should go back to the page you came from (eather A, C, D, E)

Answer (score 1):

Put in short - not really. PHP is not client-side (like JavaScript) language, but server-side one, the `header("Location: ...");` is used for that purpose - redirecting to another location. Keep in mind, that redirection *must* be done *before* any output, otherwise you'll get errors/warnings of type

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (output started at...)`.

Using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not an reliable option however.

The meaning of the `HTTP_REFERER` is the address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify `HTTP_REFERER` as a feature. **In short, it cannot really be trusted**, because it CAN be missing.

Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in 2 ways:
Option one is to use JS,

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">back</a>";
```

option 2 is to get the previous link by checking where the user came from with

```
[HTTP_REFERER]
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
and then send him to there via header("location: .."),

but keep in mind if the user gets in direct link into that page both ways aren't useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:history.back();">Go back</a>
```